# string manipulation c++ storing ints after string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to manipulate a string (below). How would I put "John" in a seperate string, 1 in an int, 2 in an int, and 3 in a double? I figured out how to get John from it.

```
string s = "John 1 2 3";
string name = s.substr(0, s.find(' ')); 
string wins = user.substr(playerOne.username.length(), user.find(' '));
string losses = user.substr(wins.length(), user.find(' '));
string winLossRatio = user.substr(losses.length(), user.find(' '));
```

Comment: I dunno, but I use `std::istringstream` so I can treat the string as an input stream.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews does that allow for more manipulation? if so how?

Comment: @Cory _"does that allow for more manipulation?"_ Yes, because it allows you to split the original string into the individual parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I put `"John"` in a seperate `string`, 1 in an `int`, 2 in an `int`, and 3 in a `double`?

Way easier to split a string into parts is to use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) instead of `std::string::find()`:

```
std::string s = "John 1 2 3";
std::string name; 
int wins;
int losses;
double winLossRatio;
std::istringstream iss(s);
iss >> name >> wins >> losses >> winLossRatio;
```

---

Closely related post: [**The most elegant way to iterate the words of a string**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would make use of `std::stringstream` :

```
std::string name;    
int wins; int losses;     
double winLossRatio;
std::stringstream ss(s);    
ss >> name >> wins >> losses >> winLossRatio;
```

Comment: @user4581301 Go ahead. It's my first time answering.

Comment: The formatting magic in answers is to use four space intent rather than the ` character. Have a line before and after the code and don't try to put intended code after a numeric list. For some reason lists screw up the rendering.

Comment: @CedricDeSchepper One little nitpick (technically you're correct). The OP asked for specific variable names and types. Best you reflect such in your answer, before seeing the OP coming up with complaints your code doesn't match their question.

Comment: @user0042 haha, nah, I'm not an idiot. Thank you guys very much. One last question, I assume I need an import to use stringstream?

Comment: @Cory #include<sstream> will do the job

Comment: @Cory The import (`#include <sstream>`) is mentioned in the reference link I provided in my answer. I never had any doubts about your intelligence, sorry if I sounded like so. It was merely a good advice for the (_beginner_) answerer here.